# "Nontype error" in attempt to calculate Binomial coefficient using factorial from math

Tags: python, math, factorial, nonetype, binomial-coefficients

For the sake of demonstrating an overflow error in relation to binomial coefficients, I wrote this code in an attempt to calculate Binomial coefficients.

I'm pretty sure its mathematically correct, but for some reason, I get the following error:

```
File "C:/Users(...)/binominal coeffesient.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(f"n = {n} k = {k}\t{binomial(n,k)}")
  File "C:/Users/(....)/binominal coeffesient.py", line 10, in binomial
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(n)*factorial(n-k))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

The code in question is:

```
def factorial(n):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        prod *= i
    print(prod)


def binomial(n, k):
    return factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))


for n in range(0,4):
    for k in range(0, n+1):
        print(f"n = {n} k = {k}\t{binomial(n,k)}")
```

It is worth noting that my IDE, Pycharm highlights, the multiplication operator * and division operator / in the function "binomial(n, k)"

Is there anyone who can help me fix this?

Comment: You don't return any value from the `factorial` function. You also want to use integer division (`//`) instead of true division (`/`) in your `binomial` function, but that's not related to the error you're reporting.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: I'm still grateful for help:-) Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Also note that factorials quickly grow very large, causing approximation errors and even overflows. An alternative calculation avoids large numbers, e.g.  `prod=1; for i in range(k): prod=prod*(n-i)//(i+1)`

Comment: @johanC: You are absolutely correct! I'm writing an assignment on exactly that topic, which is why I'm writing this code as an example of how you shouldn't solve these kinds of problems:-)

Answer (score 1):

If someone in the future might wonder how to hard code a factorial or binomial function, this is one way to do it - even if it's probably not the best.

The (very rookie mistake) was that I forgot to remove a print statement I used for testing of the factorial function, where it obviously shod have been a return statement instead.

Also, the whole number division ( // ) was a welcomed improvement to the original code.

Either way, thank you to everyone who helped and pointed out my mistakes, and helped me fix them.

This is the solution:

```
def factorial(n):
    prod = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        prod *= i
    return prod


def binomial(n, k):
    return (factorial(n)//(factorial(k)*(factorial(n-k))))

print(binomial(10,5))
```

If you are planning to use this, please note that it does not work for large numbers. Although it works fine for smaller numbers, the whole point for writing this code was to demonstrate that it causes errors whit large calculations.